# Replace matrix in list using logical expression

Tags: r

Assume you have a list of matrices `A` and `B` such that

```
A <- matrix(0,3,3)
B <- matrix(0,3,3)
mat.list <- list(A,B)
```

and you want to replace some of these matrices with a matrix `C` in the list using a logical vector. My attempt would have been the following:

```
replace <- c(T,F)   #logical vector for replacement
C <- matrix(1,3,3)  #replacement matrix
mat.list[replace] <- mat.list #my attempt
```

However, that results in a warning and no replacement takes place:

```
Warning message:
In mat.list[replace] = C :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

In a way, this was unexpected, at least to me. I suspect the combination of a logical vector and lists is probably not ideal here? Can we make this work using a logical vector that is the same length as the list has elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
A <- matrix(0,3,3)
B <- matrix(0,3,3)
mat.list <- list(A,B)
mat.list
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0

replace <- c(TRUE, FALSE)  
C <- matrix(1,3,3)  
mat.list[which(replace)] <- list(C)

mat.list
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]    1    1    1
#> [3,]    1    1    1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
```

By the way, don't use `T` and `F` in your code, or somebody will do this to you:

```r
T <- FALSE
F <- TRUE
A <- matrix(0,3,3)
B <- matrix(0,3,3)
mat.list <- list(A,B)
mat.list
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0

replace <- c(T,F)  
C <- matrix(1,3,3)  
mat.list[which(replace)] <- list(C)

mat.list
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]    1    1    1
#> [3,]    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks (also for the potentially life-saving advice)!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the replacement approaches like below

```
mat.list[replace] <- list(C)
```

or

```
mat.list[[which(replace)]] <- C
```